# Can't work out how to remove the trailing whitespace from my result

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, trailing-whitespace

My code finds the input for a balanced binary tree from an array.

```
array = [178, 57, 26, 157, 679, 397, 898]

def myFunc(x):
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        inp = x[i]
        j=i-1
        while j>=0 and inp<x[j]:
            x[j+1] = x[j]
            j-=1
        x[j+1] = inp
    x

    class tn(object):
        def __init__(self, y):
            self.val = y
            self.left = None
            self.right =None

    def sort2bst(x):
        if not x:
            return None
        m = len(x)//2
        node = tn(x[m])
        node.left = sort2bst(x[:m])
        node.right  = sort2bst(x[m+1:])
        return node


    def po(node):
        if not node:
            return
        print(node.val, end=" ")
        po(node.left)
        po(node.right)

    result = sort2bst(x)
    po(result)

myFunc(array)
```

The output looks like this: `178 57 26 157 679 397 898`

So far, I've been able to do everything except removing the trailing whitespace from the output. I have to use `end=" "` for it to output in a single line, but this means the last value also has an empty space after it. I tried to use `.rstrip()` but that's also not working because I think it only works on strings. How would I remove this whitespace at the end?

Comment: Have you tried building the string and then printing it, rather than printing it piece by piece?

Comment: You could add a counter based on the length of your array and then an if to check if you are going to print the last number, in which case you remove the end=" "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of continuously printing, you can collect the results and create the string once you have them all:

```py
def po(node):
    if not node:
        return []
    return [str(node.val), *po(node.left), *po(node.right)]

result = sort2bst(x)
print(" ".join(po(result)))
```

Comment: that's perfect! it worked exactly as I needed it to. Thank you!